React Native 0.73.9 not formatting on save with ESLINT
I recently upgraded my React Native to 0.73.9. I hadn't noticed, but my files were no longer formatted according to the Eslint config. I'm not getting suggestions from callbacks [] too. I currently use the following for formattations https://github.com/Rocketseat/eslint-config-rocketseat.
This is my file, .eslintrc.json
{
  "extends": "@rocketseat/eslint-config/react",
  "plugins": [
    "unused-imports"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "unused-imports/no-unused-imports": "error",
    "unused-imports/no-unused-vars": [
      "warn",
      {
        "vars": "all",
        "varsIgnorePattern": "^_",
        "args": "after-used",
        "argsIgnorePattern": "^_"
      }
    ]
  }
}

tsconfig.js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["ES2015", "ES2016", "ES2017", "ES2018", "ES2019", "ES2020"],
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",    
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "types": ["react-native", "jest", "styled-components-react-native"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"],
  "extends": "@react-native/typescript-config/tsconfig.json"
}

And I have the following vscode config:
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": false,
}

Example, that ; was not supposed to be there according to the Eslint configs, but when saving it doesn't get removed:
...code
function resetForm() {
    form.resetField('nome')
    form.resetField('cpf')
    form.resetField('observacoes')
    form.setValue('foto', undefined);
  }

package.json:
{

  "dependencies": {
    "@bam.tech/react-native-image-resizer": "^3.0.10",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.9.0",
    "@intercom/intercom-react-native": "^4.0.1",
    "@nozbe/watermelondb": "^0.25.5",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.7",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.3",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.11",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.24.4",
    "@uidotdev/usehooks": "^2.4.1",
    "axios": "^1.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.2",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "chroma-js": "^2.4.2",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.9",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.0.0",
    "i18next": "^22.4.9",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mime": "^4.0.1",
    "patch-package": "^8.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.45.2",
    "react-i18next": "^12.1.4",
    "react-native": "0.73.9",
    "react-native-blob-util": "^0.17.1",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-config": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.3.0",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^8.1.3",
    "react-native-drawer-layout": "^4.0.0-alpha.1",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.5.3",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
    "react-native-file-viewer": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.41.2",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-images-to-pdf": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-mask-input": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-mmkv": "^2.12.2",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^6.2.2",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.6.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.34.0",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.8.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-tcp-socket": "^6.0.6",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.6",
    "yup": "^0.32.11",
    "zustand": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.73.21",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.73.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.73.5",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.73.1",
    "@rocketseat/eslint-config": "^2.2.2",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/chroma-js": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.5.9",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-native-doc-viewer": "^2.7.2",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.13",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "@types/styled-components-react-native": "^5.1.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.54.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^8.9.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-root-import": "^6.6.0",
    "customize-cra": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.47.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-transformer": "^0.77.0",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.5.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-native-vector-icons@^9.2.0": "patch:react-native-vector-icons@npm%3A9.2.0#./.yarn/patches/react-native-vector-icons-npm-9.2.0-7e7f70fd28.patch"
  }
}


I had to add this, which I did not need before.
.vscode/settings.json
{
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": "always"
  }
}

